# What is the essential difference between neural network and linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

A neural network is a several linear transormations $L_1,\ldots, L_m$ that are sequentialy appilied to feature vector $X$. A compositon of linear transformations is a linear transformation. So after all we get $L X$ where $L$ is a composition of $L_1,\ldots, L_m$.

The question is: if eventually we have that neural network is just applying a liner transformation to a feature vector what is the essential difference betwen neural networks and linear regression

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782071/why-must-a-nonlinear-activation-function-be-used-in-a-backpropagation-neural-net

Comment: Most common activation functions for neural networks are sigmoid and hyperbolic tangent, which are not linear transformations.

Comment: The transformation may be linear but the output is almost always transformed by a non-linear function.

Comment: @StudentT but I can apply non-linear transformation to the result of a regression as well

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem which states that you need at minimum 1 hidden layer to approximate any continuous function, so perceptron is not enough

Comment: @Eugeny89 A neural network with only the output transformed non-linearly is a special case which is almost never used in practice. So Yes there is a connection between linear regression and neural networks in a special case.

Comment: FYI [What is the difference between 'regular' linear regression and deep learning linear regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/253337/12359)

Comment: Research funding.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, a neural network is not several consecutive *linear* transformations. As you note, that would only result in another linear transformation in the end, so why do many instead of one? Actually, a neural network performs several (at least one, but possibly more, depending on the number of hidden layers) *nonlinear* (e.g. sigmoid) transformations.

That is also the difference between a neural network and a linear regression, since the latter uses a *linear* combination of regressors to approximate the regressand.

Comment: (minor detail, which I guess you aware of but just for neophytes: A neural network is not *necessarily* several consecutive linear transformations.)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, thank you. Yes, a network may have $m\geq 1$ layers, so it is of course possible that $m=1$.