# How can a perceptron be used for regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, perceptron

I know perceptron is a binary classifier which has a 0/1 output. But in one of my exercises for a Neural Network course, there is a question that asks to implement a linear regression with perceptron. Unfortunately, I have no idea.

Comment: What is the question literally? There are different ways I can imagine a perceptron(/dummy variable?) in a regression.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings different features of homes are given, I should learn the price of new homes. the question wants I write a perceptron that does regression.

Comment: This is still not very clear. Is it that you are supposed to do a binary classification of expensive-cheap homes? What is literally the question (not what the question wants)?

Comment: I had asked somewhat related question. Check out. It'll surely help you - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253337/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-linear-regression-and-deep-learning-lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between linear regression and logistic regression is the activation function, which converts the logits (W$\cdot$X) to a probability-like value.

If you specifically need to keep the activation function in the perceptron algorithm, then I would say you have to consider it as a multi-class classification problem, where the classes are all the house prices. For example, class1 = 1000, class2 = 1001 ... classN = [max] price. This should give you the closest thing to regression. Look at this if you want [Multi-class Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)

You can also reduce the number of class by grouping house prices. For ex., prices [1000 - 1100] become 1050. This, however, will reduce your model's accuracy.